# How to align graph with respective rectangle node size in d3 js

Tags: html, json, d3.js

I'm using d3 js for collapsing tree.

Links need to connect end of rectangle to starting position of another rectangle. Please click here to see image
[rect nodes d3 js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdxlp.png)

But I'm not getting like that. 
Please help me to find the solution for it.

Here is the code what I'm using

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tree Example</title>
  <style>
    .node {
      cursor: pointer;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 2px 10px 4px 20px;
    }
    .node circle {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 3px;
    }
    .node rect {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 3px;
    }
    .node text {
      font: 12px sans-serif;
    }
    .link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ccc;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- load the d3.js library -->
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    var treeData = [{
      "name": "Top Level",
      "parent": "null",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Level 2: A",
        "parent": "Top Level",
        "children": [{
          "name": "Son of A",
          "parent": "Level 2: A"
        }, {
          "name": "Daughter of A",
          "parent": "Level 2: A"
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "Level 2: B",
        "parent": "Top Level"
      }]
    }];


     // ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 120,
        bottom: 20,
        left: 120
      },
      width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var i = 0,
      duration = 750,
      root;

    var tree = d3.layout.tree()
      .size([height, width]);

    var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
      .projection(function(d) {
        return [d.y, d.x];
      });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    root = treeData[0];
    root.x0 = height / 2;
    root.y0 = 0;

    update(root);

    d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "500px");

    function update(source) {

      // Compute the new tree layout.
      var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
        links = tree.links(nodes);

      // Normalize for fixed-depth.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.y = d.depth * 180;
      });

      // Update the nodes…
      var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(nodes, function(d) {
          return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
        });

      // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
      var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
        })
        .on("click", click);

      nodeEnter.append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? 0 : 0;
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? 15 : 15;
        })
        .attr("rx", 10)
        .attr("ry", 10)
        .attr("width", 10)
        .attr("height", 10)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
        });

      nodeEnter.append("text")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? 60 : 13;
        })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
        })
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.name;
        })
        .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

      // Transition nodes to their new position.
      var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
        });

      nodeUpdate.select("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? 0 : 0;
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? -15 : -15;
        })
        .attr("rx", 10)
        .attr("ry", 10)
        .attr("width", 150)
        .attr("height", 30)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
        });

      nodeUpdate.select("text")
        .style("fill-opacity", 1);

      // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
      var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
        })
        .remove();

      nodeExit.select("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? 0 : 0;
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? 15 : 15;
        })
        .attr("rx", 10)
        .attr("ry", 10)
        .attr("width", 10)
        .attr("height", 10);

      nodeExit.select("text")
        .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

      // Update the links…
      var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
        .data(links, function(d) {
          return d.target.id;
        });

      // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
      link.enter().insert("path", "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
          var o = {
            x: source.x0,
            y: source.y0
          };
          return diagonal({
            source: o,
            target: o
          });
        });

      // Transition links to their new position.
      link.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", diagonal);

      // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
      link.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", function(d) {
          var o = {
            x: source.x,
            y: source.y
          };
          return diagonal({
            source: o,
            target: o
          });
        })
        .remove();

      // Stash the old positions for transition.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
      });
    }

     // Toggle children on click.
    function click(d) {
      if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
      update(d);
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all your rectangles have 150px of width, we can hardcode that value in the diagonal function:

```
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .source(function (d) {
        return {"x": d.source.x, "y": d.source.y + 150};
    })
    .projection(function (d) { return [d.y + 0, d.x + 0];
});
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8xxx3mhm/